# How to reference newrelic keys via settings.py

Tags: python, django, newrelic

I am just using NewRelic for the first time. I have the new `relic.ini` file, which includes the `license_key` and `app_name` hard coded, in my Django Python repository and have updated my manage.py script to be as so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize('newrelic.ini')

import os
import sys


def main():

  .....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run my api locally via `./manage.py runserver` I can see the logs being tracked in NewRelic which is good.

However, I'm wanting to remove the hardcoded `license_key` and `app_name` from the `newrelic.ini` file so that I can reference environment variables. I have read this documentation https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/python-agent/configuration/python-agent-configuration/#server-side-configuration which outlines the environment and config variables.

I added this to my `settings.py` file so that I can override the env variables on deployment:

```
NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME = "My API"

NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

I have tried

- removing `license_key` and `app_name` entirely from newrelic.ini
- keeping the variables but setting them equal to ""
- keeping the variables but setting license_key = NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY

but I can't seem to get it tracking without it being hardcoded in the newrelic.ini file

So my question - how can I use environment variables with the newrelic.ini file?

thanks in advance